# How to automatically add Request to all path operations in class based views in FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi

In [FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/) using [Class Based Views](https://fastapi-utils.davidmontague.xyz/user-guide/class-based-views/)
I know how to add a request to every path operation manually:

```py
from fastapi import Depends, Request
from fastapi_utils.cbv import cbv
from fastapi_utils.inferring_router import InferringRouter

router = InferringRouter()

@cbv(router)
class Router:

    @router.get('/test/1')
    def test1(self, request: Request):
        return {'headers': request.headers}
```

I know how to add a dependency to all path operations automatically:

```py
def get_dbs() -> str:
    return 'This is DB session'

@cbv(router)
class Router:
    dbs: str = Depends(get_dbs)

    @router.get('/test/2')
    def test2(self):
        return {'db_session': self.dbs}
```

But I could not find out **how to add the current request automatically to all path operations** in [Class Based Views](https://fastapi-utils.davidmontague.xyz/user-guide/class-based-views/). All sources I came across point to a manual approach - to define a request in the function signature as shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also get the request as a class-level dependency. Like so:

```
@cbv(router)
class Router:
    request: Request

    @router.get('/test/1')
    async def test1(self):
        return {'headers': self.request.headers}
```